# remove document field on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to update a document. So, each time I want to update a object I serialize it and I send it to ES. Imagine a POJO object with.

```
obj.status = 20;
obj.description = "raw description";
```

When I update this object it's serialized and indexed on ES as:

```
{
    status: 20,
    description: "raw description"
}
```

So, I need now update this object as:

```
obj.status = null;
```

Then, I serialize it:

```
{
    description: "raw description"
}
```

The problem is, from now then, I don't want `status` is indexed. The problem is that ES merges this object with the indexed previous one. So, on index this document is:

```
{
    status: 20,
    description: "raw description"
}
```

So, I need to "remove" this field from index.

Any ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the index API or the update API?

Comment: I'm using update API.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions.

1. Use the Update API with *script* instead of *doc*
2. Use the Index API, by reindexing a document with same Id you can remove a field. The Index API behaves likes an upsert.

Code examples:

```
# Update API with Script
POST your_index/your_type/1/_update
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"status\")"
}
# Index API to reindex
PUT your_index/your_type/1
{
    description: "raw description"
}
```

The Update API triggers a Read before Write, whereas the Index API only triggers a Write.